# How to include train sector in HERE generated road routes?

Tags: here-api

We have a question.

On HERE maps can we generate the truck route including RO-LA / train?

For example: The route will be from Kufstein-Austria to Italy-Milan, but from Worgl to Brenner or from Worgl to Trento the truck takes the train, and from Trento continue its way on the road).

For ferry I know it is, but for train there is this possibility?

Answer (score 0):

There is support for only limited Train routes for Truck routing available via the HERE Routing API, like the channel tunnel. The other train routes are not supported by the API at the moment.